# Can I do synchronous cross-domain communicating with window.postMessage?

Tags: javascript, html, cross-domain, postmessage

I'm thinking of using [window.postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage) directly for cross-domain communication.

If I do:

1. `postMessage()` from the parent frame
2. Load an iframe
3. `window.addEventListener("message", callback, false);` from the child iframe

When will the messages I posted before loading the iframe be executed? Are they guaranteed to be executed at all? Are there timing guarantees?

I would like to pass a parameter from the top frame that influences the initialization of the child frame.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The postMessage() function is asynchronous, meaning it will return immediately. So you can not do synchronous communication with it.

In your example, the posted message will vanish in the void, because there is no listener for the message event at the time the postMessage() function is executed.

If you would load the iframe first and call postMessage() afterwards, then there could be a timing issue, maybe. (From my experience there is none, the parent code is always executed first, but I am not sure about this point.)

Below is my solution for the problem of not knowing exactly when the iframe will be ready.

*In the parent window:*

1. Load the iframe (this is asynchronous, too)
2. Set up message listener
3. Post message to the iframe (just trying here)
4. Wait for more messages to come

*In the iframe:*

1. Set up message listener
2. Post message to the parent window (just trying here)
3. Wait for more messages to come

Whoever receives the first message from the other side then starts the real communication.

In my experience, the message from the parent to the iframe always gets lost, so the communication starts when the parent receives the message from the iframe. But in this setup it is not important which one starts first.

Comment: "The postMessage() function is asynchronous, meaning it will return immediately." 

Do you mean it won't return immediately? Synchronous means it will return immediately

Comment: I believe postMessage's return type is `void` or `None (undefined)` according to MDN. So it is meant to be ignored. It does not return immediately something useful like Promises do. I think of it as a side effect that we are not tracking.

Answer (score 1):

To send the first message to the iframe from the parent window, you can only do it once the iframe is loaded and before that you can not even send the message from child to parent.
So in order to do so provide a onload handler for the iframe so that you can use the postmessge().
Consider the following code for the same.

```
ifrm.setAttribute('src','www.yoururl.com'));
document.body.appendChild(ifrm);
ifrm.onload = function() {
   this.contentWindow.postMessage(dataObject,'targetWindow');
}
```